# use of .seek(0) for fileinput method

Tags: python, file-io

I have a problem reading 2 sets of files. I use the module `fileinput` because I need to read two sets of files once in production.
The problem occured when I am trying to reset the handle on the second files in the second loop:

```
fileC = fileinput.FileInput()
#with  sys.stdin as fileC, open(filenameA,'r') as fileA:


#lineC = sys.stdin.readline()

for lineC in fileC:
     fieldC = lineC.split('#')
     #set the pointer to the begining of fileA
     fileA = fileinput.FileInput(glob.glob(locationA2))
     #Initialize p to 0
     p = 0
     for lineA in fileA:
         fieldA = lineA.split('#')
         #Write all the element that have no corresponding conversion
         if (fieldA[0] == fieldC[0]) and (fieldA[2] == fieldC[2]) and (fieldA[1] < fieldC[1]):
             p = 1
     if p == 0:
        #outputfile.write(lineC)
         sys.stdout.write(lineC)
```

`fileA` is defined in the 1st `for` loop as I couldn't find an altenative to `fileA.seek(0)` as it doesn't work with `FileInput`. The problem is that the `FileInput()` is in the loop and it isn't really optimized on a timely manner.

Any idea on this ?

Thanks

Comment: What benefit is fileinput giving you vs. using regular files?

Comment: if files are not big, load files in list